# How much work should be done in shaders in opengl?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glsl, shader

Should I avoid doing excess calculations in the shaders in opengl?

For example: Things that need to be calculated every frame such as lighting. Should I do the calculations then send the results to the shaders, or should I just do the calculations in the shaders?

Comment: How I remember it is anything parallelizable should be done on the GPU, anything sequential should be done on the CPU.

Comment: Also consider that there are multiple types of shaders; typically some lighting occurs in the vertex shaders, and the results used the fragment shaders.

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered. Which computations you do where depends on exactly what those calculations are, what the visual effect of doing them in other places, etc. It's not something you can give a general recommendation for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPU vs CPU is a huge topic of discussion and as @Nicol Bolas points out the question is looking for a general solution where a multitude of factors will impact the result.

When considering performance nothing beats profiling.  Humans are notoriously bad at predicting the performance implications of their applications.  If during development you notice that you are suddenly GPU bound then you may want to offload some of the work to the CPU.  On the other hand if you are CPU bound you may have the option of offloading more work to the GPU even if that work has nothing to do with graphics.  More than likely you will want to start off by giving the GPU what you can (especially if it is graphics related anyway) to free up your CPU cycles.

You can read a bit more about profiling GPUs on [NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com) and [AMD](http://developer.amd.com/) developer websites or by searching for GPU profiling tutorials/blog posts such as [this](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2011/10/12/gpu-profiling-101/).

[GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU) has become a major topic of discussion in the world of parallel programming as GPUs were designed with parallelism in mind.  It is also not uncommon to add multiple GPUs to a system using technologies such as [SLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Link_Interface) to further parallelize the processing.  This is one of the principles of @Patashu's comment to favor parallel processing for the GPU. If your interested in learning more you can dig into two of the more popular GPU based parallel programming platforms [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) and [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA).

The topic is also discussed a bit more in the following posts:

- [CPU vs GPU](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88356/opengl-cpu-vs-gpu)
- [Shaders for general calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915001/using-shader-for-calculations)
- [An Example of sticking with the CPU](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31529/should-the-modelview-and-projection-matrices-be-calculated-in-the-shader-or-on-t)

It would also be a good idea to read up on the [GPU gems](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-gems) series among other publications.  You will likely find results others have had with splitting up the workload.